# Laravel sms sending

Tags: php, sms, laravel-5.3

I am developing web based application using the laravel framework. I need to send text messages to all users in the system. I found lot of gateways for sending sms messages which are not free.

Is There a way to send text messages using a GSM modem in the laravel framework?

Comment: Have you attempted to do this already or have found anything on a Google search?

Comment: I have attempted. But normal php script for sms sending is not working in laravel framework. I tried packages also. but all of them are not free. Thats why  I need a way to send sms using gsm modem